# Close form when clicking on button

Tags: c#, winforms

I was here testing a situation in which the main form (Form1) when initiating also opens Form3 and when clicking on a button opens Form2 and closes Form3. But I'm  getting Form3 continuously open, no close when clicking on the button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TESTE2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Form test = new Form3();
            test.Show();
        }

        private Form3 form3;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form test = new Form3();

            test.Close();
            Form test2 = new Form2();
            test2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You declare `private Form3 form3;` but it looks like you forgot to actually use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a different reference to open the form and to close it.
Here's a revised version of your code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form3 form3;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form3.Close();
        Form test2 = new Form2();
        test2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```